# Bit threads as noisy quantum channels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, research-level, holographic-principle

In literature on the holographic duality, recently [a new way](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00354) of looking at the Ryu-Takayanagi formula has been presented, where the minimal surface area has been replaced by the maximum number of "bit-threads" that can emanate from a boundary region.

If the entanglement entropy of the boundary region $A$ is $S(A)$, then the new paper says there will be $S(A)$ bit-threads emanating from the region and ending on the rest of the boundary. Each bit-thread carries one qubit of information.

So if we think of a bit-thread as a noiseless qubit channel, we have that $S(A)$ uses of the noiseless qubit channel are needed to carry information between the boundary region $A$ and the rest of the boundary. This, being essentially the statement of Schumacher's quantum data compression theorem, made me wonder: if for some reason we only had noisy qubit channels, in which case we know that we need more than $S(A)$ uses to carry information on the state of $A$ to the rest of the boundary, what effect on the metric of space would there be?

To summarize: Can we think of these bit-threads as noiseless qubit channels traversing the bulk? If so, what effect is there on the metric of space if these channels became noisy?

Comment: If you allow me to speculate alongside you-- as you said, noisy qubit channels means more than $S(A)$ is needed, which effectively increases $S(A)$ for all regions. Which means *all* minimal surfaces have more area than the noiseless case. This is a rescaling, it can't change the symmetries of the metric, so I'd guess it simply increases $\ell_{AdS} \propto S(A)$.

Comment: Possibly silly follow-up question: what if some of the bit-threads are noisy and some of them aren't, depending on which part of the bulk they travel in?